# Connecting mininet host to the internet

Tags: networking, sdn, mininet, pox, ryu

I've tried creating a simple topo with 1 switch (s1) and 1 host (h1). As suggested on the the internet, I've add a port to the switch 's1' with

```
ovs-vsctl add-port s1 enp0s3
```

and configure the host with

```
ifconfig h1-eth0 0
dhclient h1-eth0
```

To my understanding, what i've done is adding a new port to the switch (to my network interface, enp0s3), so that mininet host that is connected to the switch can connect to the internet. Then setting up a dhcp server at host h1.

However, i still can't ping any server/website from host h1. Pinging it directly from the virtual machine does works btw.

Any other method that i could've done to connect mininet host to internet?

Answer (score 1):

I've found the simplest solution,

add --nat in the command.
eg. sudo mn --topo --nat

But this doesn't guarantee which switches will be connected the internet especially if you have multi-layer topology (> 2)

Check out mininet FAQ for more details on adding own's topo and controller for connection the host thru NAT.

Comment: Would you add contents in possible issue in multi layer? If the one layer like switch and host, does host reach to the Internet through switch?

Answer (score 1):

if you use python, it has a simply way to set it, in examples/nat.py:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

"""
Example to create a Mininet topology and connect it to the internet via NAT
"""


from mininet.cli import CLI
from mininet.log import lg, info
from mininet.topolib import TreeNet


if __name__ == '__main__':
    lg.setLogLevel( 'info')
    net = TreeNet( depth=1, fanout=4 )
    # Add NAT connectivity
    net.addNAT().configDefault()
    net.start()
    info( "*** Hosts are running and should have internet connectivity\n" )
    info( "*** Type 'exit' or control-D to shut down network\n" )
    CLI( net )
    # Shut down NAT
    net.stop()
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code. I ran the code outside of virtual environment, and the code looks like down the network (hanging at `net.addNAT().configDefault()`) . What could be the cause?

Comment: Another observation is host IP address. It is automatically 10.0.0.x that is private network (non bounding address)...how to reach to the Internet?